# Why do I get a different answer from the use of TrigExpand?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

This is an old post but I get two different answers from *Mathematica* 9.0.1.0

```
f[x_] =  Sin[x]^3 + Cos[x]^2 /. 
    AlgebraicRules[{Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1, Sin[3*x] == 1/2}]

(* 1 - Sin[x]^2 + Sin[x]^3 *)

g[x_] = Sin[x]^3 + Cos[x]^2 /. 
    AlgebraicRules[{Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1, TrigExpand[Sin[3*x]] == 1/2}]

(*  7/8 + (3 Sin[x])/4 - Sin[x]^2 *)

Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π }]
```

[image]

The plot shows that `f[x]` and `g[x]` are clearly different. It appears that the use of `TrigExpand[Sin[3*x]]` in `g[x]` messes up the answer.

Comment: `AlgebraicRules` became obsolete in MMA 3 according to http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/functions/AlgebraicRules. In fact I can't even find a documentation page describing its use and purpose and `?AlgebraicRules` gives me some odd things too.

Comment: Just replace = with :=

Answer (score 3):

First note that you don't use the delayed assignment `:=`, so both of your right-hand side expressions are evaluated where you define them. (Otherwise, you would get the same result for concrete numeric values as `TrigExpand[a] == a`.)

I don't know what you're attempting to solve but I think I can answer your question anyway. Note that since `TrigExpand[Sin[3 x]]` gives an polynomial of `Sin[x]` and `Cos[x]`, the `AlgebraicRules` in the `g` expression case is solved only in them as variables, whilst in the `f` expression case also in terms of `Sin[3 x]`. Consequently, in the `f` case, the second equation is not accounted for and what you get is only reduction with respect to the first equation. More specifically, what you get are results of the following terms rewriting rules:

```
(* f *) Sin[x]^3 + Cos[x]^2 /. { Cos[x]^2 -> 1 - Sin[x]^2,  Sin[3 x] -> 1/2 }
(* g *) Sin[x]^3 + Cos[x]^2 /. { Cos[x]^2 -> 1 - Sin[x]^2,  Sin[x]^3 -> (-1 + 6 Sin[x])/8 }
```

Cf.:

```
AlgebraicRules[{Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1, TrigExpand[Sin[3 x]] == 1/2}][[6]]
AlgebraicRules[{Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1, Sin[3 x] == 1/2}][[6]]
```