# Is AlgebraicRulesData magical?

Tags: equation-solving, undocumented, algebra

I am trying to understand what `AlgebraicRules` is all about in the answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29078/2048) question.  It apparently returns an `AlgebraicRulesData` with the following usage:

> AlgebraicRulesData is an object returned by AlgebraicRules. Its OutputForm appears to be a list of rules, but the rules will be used algebraically rather than syntactically by Replace and related functions.

That's weird!  Observe:

```
ex = AlgebraicRules[
  {x^2 + 2y - 4 == 6, x^2 + y^2 == 0}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> AlgebraicRulesData[{Solve`SolvVar[x],Solve`SolvVar[y]},{x,y},
>   -10+Solve`SolvVar[x]^2+2 Solve`SolvVar[y]==0&&Solve`SolvVar[x]^2+Solve`SolvVar[y]^2==0,
>   {{{0,{{2,1},{1,-2},{0,10}}}},{{2,{{0,1}}},{0,{{1,2},{0,-10}}}}},
>   {x,y},{y^2->-10+2 y,x^2->10-2 y},Rational]
> ```

Apparently, I can use `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) with this, and I don't get a `ReplaceAll::reps` error!

```
x^2 /. ex

(*  10 - 2*y  *)
```

Even weirder is that if I copy the entire output and try to literally replace with it, *it doesn't work!*  I get an `AlgebraicRules::algdat` error.

```
x^2 /. AlgebraicRulesData[{Solve`SolvVar[x],Solve`SolvVar[y]},{x,y},
  -10+Solve`SolvVar[x]^2+2 Solve`SolvVar[y]==0&&Solve`SolvVar[x]^2+Solve`SolvVar[y]^2==0,
  {{{0,{{2,1},{1,-2},{0,10}}}},{{2,{{0,1}}},{0,{{1,2},{0,-10}}}}},
  {x,y},{y^2->-10+2 y,x^2->10-2 y},Rational]

(* x^2 *)
```

Would someone explain to me what is happening that allows `ex` to be used as a replacement rule, but not the literal expression?

Comment: You've run into the fact that Mathematica isn't actually an immutable perfectly [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) language (BTW I'm pretty sure there is no such language since they all need some kind of mutable internal representation). In essence, there's a constructed `AlgebraicRulesData` that the C++ side of the kernel knows how to work with, but which can't be constructed by just calling `AlgebraicRulesData` on its data. It's good to keep in mind that everything we work with in Mathematica is really a C++ object. Helps you write better code.

Comment: Really?  How do you know that?  I've never seen this behavior anywhere else.

Comment: Think about this: `{AssociationQ@<|1 -> 2|>, AssociationQ@Unevaluated[<|1 -> 2|>], Head@Unevaluated[<|1 -> 2|>]}` The data itself is the same, and yet `AssociationQ` says that one is `True` and one is not. You can also set special bits with, e.g. ``System`Private`HoldSetNoEntry`` that won't be copied if you copy-paste the expression, but which will be held if you keep them bound to a variable or otherwise preserve the identity of the expression (e.g. by just passing it through your code). There are good number of places where this is used productively on this site.

Comment: (1) What `AlgebraicRulesData` really is, is obsolete.Yes, it is still supported. Or ignored, to be more accurate. As for the copy/paste business, it has an internal validation flag. Those do not survive copying and in the case of `AlgebraicRulesData` there is no way (or attempt) to revalidate them. Without the flag being set, rule replacement will not handle them.

Comment: (2) The comments by @b3m2a1 are quite on the mark, especially in giving an indication of how validation flags might be used.

Comment: Very interesting!  Thanks for the explanations.  Either @b3m2a1 or DanielLichtblau should write this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I'll copy my comments in an answer so that it has one. As it involves details of internals I once worked on, this will be as a community wiki (so no bounty, alas). No objection if that goes to @b3m2a1 though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) What AlgebraicRulesData really is, is obsolete.Yes, it is still supported. Or ignored, to be more accurate. As for the copy/paste business, it has an internal validation flag. Those do not survive copying and in the case of AlgebraicRulesData there is no way (or attempt) to revalidate them. Without the flag being set, rule replacement will not handle them.

(2) The comments by @b3m2a1 are quite on the mark, especially in giving an indication of how validation flags might be used.

Comment: Hi @DanielLichtblau,  Is it possible internally flag an user-created expressions for validation?  This seems to be especially useful for avoiding expensive revalidation of large expressions.

Comment: @QuantumDot Could try using `System\`Private\`` context functions such as `SetValid` but I will note that this can have unforeseen consequences.

Comment: Thank you.  It seems ``System`Private`ValidQ`` yields `True` for expressions that were not previously declared with ``System`Private`SetValid``.  For example ``System`Private`ValidQ[x+1]`` yields `True`.  Have I miss understood it?  Thank you again!

Comment: @QuantumDot Probably means the evaluator has marked them as valid already, so they do not get reevaluated ad infinitum.